# QRScannerライブラリをObjective-Cプログラムで利用したいです。

Tags: swift, objective-c, iphone

OSSのQRScannerライブラリ（swift）をアプリ（objective-c）に入れたいのですが、苦戦しています。組み込む作業自体は自前でやることを考えており、その手順を教えていただければと思います。下記にて、現状行っている手順、疑問点、問題点を明記します。経験ある方にぜひ教えていただけるとありがたいです。

#### 要望

・以下、QRScannerライブラリをObjective-Cプログラムで利用できるように手順を教えていただけるとありがたいです。
QRScannerライブラリ
https://github.com/mercari/QRScanner

#### 前提

・CocoaPodsは利用していない。
・QRScanner.xcodeprojをプロジェクトに取り込み、Frameworksを追加。
・Usageに従い、実装。
・ベースプログラムはObjective-Cで記述、QRScannerはSwift。

#### 手順・疑問・問題点

・Swiftブリッジの[ProjectName]-Swift.hが作られない。仮に上記を自前でファイルを作りimport。
　→何らかの設定不足か？Define ModuleはYesにしてある。
・.hファイルにQRScannerViewDelegateを記述。Cannot find protocol declaration forエラーになる。
　→ヘッダの循環参照が生じている？自前で作成したのが問題？
　→あるいは、QRScannerViewDelegateのprotocolに@objc記述がないのが原因？
・.mファイルに、QRScannerView allocを記述。クラスは認識している模様。
　右クリックJump to Definitionでクラスが見れる。
・QRScannerView startRunningがエラーにはならないが、Jump to Definitionで直接該当メソッドに飛ばない。
→メソッドが正しく認識されていない？

Comment: ソースコードを見ましたが、Objective-Cから利用することを考慮したコードにはなっていませんでした。(Objective-Cでは使えないSwiftのstructやenumを使っている、メソッドに`@objc`が付与されていない、など。)ご自身で、もしくは作者に連絡して、ソースコードを修正しないといけません。Objective-Cからは使えないデータ型を使用している部分が公開メソッドにもあったりするために、かなりの書き換えが必要になるでしょう。事実上「Objective-Cからは使えない」と思った方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 「ほぼ不可能」みたいな書き方をしてしまいましたが、Objective-C側に見えないといけないのは`public`なprotocolやプロパティ・メソッドだけですし、それほど大きなソースでもないので、Objective-CとSwiftの双方に精通していて、その間のブリッジングについても詳しいと言う人がいれば、「Objective-Cからは使えないデータ型を使用している」の回避策も含めて、なんとか回答として書ける規模かもしれません。ご自身でソース修正を行うつもりがある、と言うのであれば、モジュール定義に関わる面倒がないように、QRScanner.xcodeprojを取り込むのではなく、ソースファイル(たった2本です)だけを取り込んだ方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: ソースコードまで確認いただきありがとうございます。やはり、直接は呼び出せないということですね。ソースファイルの修正で対応するようにします。